# Is there any plugin available for breakman in rubymine?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine, brakeman

Im planning to use brakeman in my ruby app , is there any way to use brakeman in rubymine ? (able to configure robocop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there's no plugin for that, but there's a feature request on RubyMine's tracker for adding support to Brakeman so your vote is welcome: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17517